# Selection from Drop Down list should show result

Tags: vba, excel

I placed a dropdown in A1 as "Cars" and "Bikes" and once I select "cars" or "bikes" it should show the list of brands from sheet5 for respective cars and bikes.

I have to run a macro once I select "cars" or "bikes" from the dropdown.

But once I select any one from dropdown the results should show instead of running macro module.

I used below in module

```
Sub validation()

    Dim MyList(2) As String
    MyList(0) = "Cars"
    MyList(1) = "Bikes"
    MyList(2) = ""

    With Range("A1").validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(MyList, ",")
    End With

    If Range("A1") = "Cars"
        Sheets("Sheet5").Range("Carsbrand").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E17")
        'the above line copies car brand names from sheet5
    ElseIf Range("A1") = "Bikes" Then
        Sheets("Sheet5").Range("Bikesbrand").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E11")
        'the above line copies car brand names from sheet5
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets up *Data Validation* in cell **A1**, but it does not actually put anything in **A1**, therefore neither list is copied.

You need another, *Event* macro, to monitor changes to cell **A1** and perform the copy.  Put this in the **worksheet code area**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim A1 As Range
   Set A1 = Range("A1")
   If Intersect(A1, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      If Range("A1") = "Cars" Then
             Sheets("Sheet5").Range("Carsbrand").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E17")
      ElseIf Range("A1") = "Bikes" Then
          Sheets("Sheet5").Range("Bikesbrand").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E11")
      End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will avoid the warning message and clean up the destination area before trying to paste:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim A1 As Range
   Set A1 = Range("A1")
   If Intersect(A1, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E17").Clear
      If Range("A1") = "Cars" Then
             Sheets("Sheet5").Range("Carsbrand").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E17")
      ElseIf Range("A1") = "Bikes" Then
          Sheets("Sheet5").Range("Bikesbrand").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B9:E11")
      End If
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the corrections,however since data for cars is of 10 cells and data for bike is of 8 cells, then last 2 cells of car remains same if bike is selected.So I Used below "Rows("9:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True" as below. but its asking do you wnat to replace the existing data if we select the other dropdown                                                                         
      If Range("A1") = "Bike" Then
             Rows("8:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Comment: @SrinivasMantri  It is easy to avoid the warning from Excel....I will **EDIT** my answer

Comment: @SrinivasMantri  See my **EDIT#1.**

Answer (score -2):

If I've understood you correctly, you would like the macro to run itself as soon as an option in Cell A1 has been selected?

Comment: Yes, thats my requirement